# Using PyParsing to parse language with signficant newlines (like Python)

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I am implementing a language where the newlines are significant, sometime, as in Python, with exactly the same rules.

For the purpose of my question we can take the Python fragment that has to do with assignments, parentheses, and the treatment of newlines and semicolons.

For example, one could write:

```py
a = 1 + 2 + 3    # ok
b = c
```

but not

```py
a = 1 + 2 + 3     b = c   # incorrect
```

because one needs a newline to divide the two statements.

However we can have

```py
a = 1 + 2 + 3;     b = c   # ok
```

using the semicolon.

Also it is not allowed to have

```py
a = 1 + 2 +   # incorrect
3
b = c
```

because there cannot be line breaks in a statement.

However, it is possible to have

```py
a = 1 + 2 + (     # ok
3)
b = c
```

or

```py
a = 1 + 2 + \     # ok
3
b = c
```

I have been trying to implement the rules above but I'm stuck.

First, I use

```py
ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(' \t')
```

so that now `\n` is significant.

I manage well to impose newlines as a separator using

```
lines = ZeroOrMore(line + OneOrMore(LineEnd()))
```

A variation of this allows to have `;` as separator as well. (I cannot quite deal with the continuation bracket `\`.)

I use `infixNotation` to define `+`, `-`, `/`, `*`.

The part that I am stuck with is that newlines should be ignored inside the parantheses, like in this case:

```py
a = 1 + 2 + ( 
3 +
1)
```

I think here something that can play a role is using `setWhitespaceChars` on the parentheses expression `(LPAR + term + RPAR)` that infixNotation generates, however, that does not work because the whitespace characters are not inherited by the lower expressions.

Does anybody have any hint?

My question can also be expressed as "how do I parse (a fragment of) Python with pyParsing?". I thought I could find some example project, but I didn't. Googling, I have seen people refer to the examples in the pyParsing repo, however `parsePythonValue.py` is about parsing values (which I can do already) and not dealing with significant newlines, and `pythongGrammarParsing.py` is about parsing the BNF grammar for Python, not parsing Python.

Comment: You've already covered all my obvious initial ideas. I also considered adding an ignore("\n") to your arithmetic expression, but then that would accept unparenthesized newlines.

Comment: Thanks, Paul, for a quick answer. I guess if you don't know how to do it, it cannot be done. Thanks for the awesome work! I've used PyParsing for almost a decade now.

Comment: Whoa, whoe! Let's not be hasty! I never said it couldn't be done, just that my initial thoughts were already covered in your own efforts. I *have* come up with a (mmm, messy?) solution, see below.

Comment: Hi, Paul, the answer you wrote disappeared somehow... did you delete it?

Comment: I did - it required changes to pyparsing code that were themselves buggy. I can undelete it to give you an idea of the approach I was thinking of.

Comment: Oh, ok. Yes, it does seem a bit more involved - honestly I would be afraid to add additional state like that, as it could make debugging harder.

Comment: Another option I was thinking was to create 2 copies of the expression grammar, one where \n is significant, one where it is not, and then modify the infixNotation to have it use the \n-insensitive grammar inside of parentheses. 

In practice this means that \n is significant globally, but then in the second copy of the grammar you set for each element that \n is whitespace. It seems very messy as well.

Comment: It seems to me that one common feature of many languages is that parentheses are balanced (once you exclude comments) and inside parentheses some special rules apply (e.g. different whitespace). If I am not mistaken, this is always true in Python: whenever there is a parenthesis newlines are not significant anymore (e.g. in the definition of a function.)  Maybe this could be useful enough to have a special treatment in PyParsing? (just like infixNotation)

Comment: I agree. Please open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/issues/206

Answer (score -1):

NOTE: THIS IS NOT A WORKING SOLUTION (at least not yet). IT RELIES ON UNRELEASED CHANGES TO PYPARSING, WHICH DON'T EVEN PASS ALL UNIT TESTS YET. I AM POSTING IT JUST AS A WAY TO DESCRIBE A POSSIBLE APPROACH TO A SOLUTION.

Ooof! This was a lot more difficult than I thought it should be. To implement, I used pyparsing's ignore mechanism with parse actions attached to the `lpar` and `rpar` expressions to ignore `<NL>`'s inside parens, but not outside. This also required adding the ability to clear the `ignoreExprs` list by calling `expr.ignore(None)`. Here is how your code might look:

```
import pyparsing as pp

# works with and without packrat
pp.ParserElement.enablePackrat()

pp.ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(' \t')

operand = pp.Word(pp.nums)
var = pp.Word(pp.alphas)

arith_expr = pp.Forward()
arith_expr.ignore(pp.pythonStyleComment)
lpar = pp.Suppress("(")
rpar = pp.Suppress(")")

# code to implement selective ignore of NL's inside ()'s
NL = pp.Suppress("\n")
base_ignore = arith_expr.ignoreExprs[:]
ignore_stack = base_ignore[:]
def lpar_pa():
    ignore_stack.append(NL)
    arith_expr.ignore(NL)
    #~ print('post-push', arith_expr.ignoreExprs)
def rpar_pa():
    ignore_stack.pop(-1)
    arith_expr.ignore(None)
    for e in ignore_stack:
        arith_expr.ignore(e)
    #~ print('post-pop', arith_expr.ignoreExprs)
def reset_stack(*args):
    arith_expr.ignore(None)
    for e in base_ignore:
        arith_expr.ignore(e)
    #~ print('post-reset', arith_expr.ignoreExprs)
lpar.addParseAction(lpar_pa)
rpar.addParseAction(rpar_pa)
arith_expr.setFailAction(reset_stack)
arith_expr.addParseAction(reset_stack)

# now define the infix notation as usual
arith_expr <<= pp.infixNotation(operand | var,
    [
    ("-", 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT),
    (pp.oneOf("* /"), 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT),
    (pp.oneOf("- +"), 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT),
    ],
    lpar=lpar, rpar=rpar
    )

assignment = var + '=' + arith_expr

# Try it out!
assignment.runTests([
"""a = 1 + 3""",
"""a = (1 + 3)""",
"""a = 1 + 2 + ( 
3 +
1)""",
"""a = 1 + 2 + (( 
3 +
1))""",
"""a = 1 + 2 +   
3""",
], fullDump=False)
```

Prints:

```
a = 1 + 3
['a', '=', ['1', '+', '3']]
a = (1 + 3)
['a', '=', ['1', '+', '3']]
a = 1 + 2 + ( 
3 +
1)
['a', '=', ['1', '+', '2', '+', ['3', '+', '1']]]
a = 1 + 2 + (( 
3 +
1))
['a', '=', ['1', '+', '2', '+', ['3', '+', '1']]]
a = 1 + 2 +   
3
a = 1 + 2 +   
          ^
FAIL: Expected end of text, found '+'  (at char 10), (line:1, col:11)>Exit code: 0
```

So it is not out of the realm of possibility, but it does take some heroic efforts.

Comment: I tried running an additional test on [Ideone](https://ideone.com/NK9Y5y), but every test failed with `FAIL-EXCEPTION: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'`. Does this code need some minimum PyParsing version? (Ideone has PyParsing 2.4.0.)

Comment: Anyway, I'm not familiar with the details of PyParsing, but that `reset_stack` looks suspicious - it looks like `a = (1 + (2 + 3) + 4)` with a newline before `4` would fail to parse due to the stack being reset after the nested `arith_expr`.

Comment: ...or, no, you've got that `pp.infixNotation` thing instead of nesting `arith_expr`.

Comment: Sadly, this required some changes to pyparsing.py itself, and these changes don't even pass my other unit tests, so they still need some work. I think I'll delete this answer for now, since it isn't really much help beyond saying "this may be theorietically possible."