# Restrict new lines in specific pyparsing expressions

Tags: python, pyparsing

Similar question: [Using PyParsing to parse language with signficant newlines (like Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169403/using-pyparsing-to-parse-language-with-signficant-newlines-like-python)

---

I enjoy the feature of pyparsing that ignores whitespaces in general, but there are some expressions in my syntax, which must be written on the same line.

The question is: **how do I restrict line breaks for specific expression?**

I see the `setWhitespaceChars` method in the docs, which should do exactly this, but it doesn't seem to work (see examples below).

### Examples

I need to parse the following expression:

```
{
    ref: 4121!
}
```

Here the curly braces may be formatted with new lines, but the `ref` part must be a one-liner.

I define syntax:

```py
>>> import pyparsing as pp
>>> ref = pp.CaselessLiteral('ref:') + pp.Word(pp.nums) + '!'
>>> braces = '{' + ref + '}'
```

Now I try to change whitespaces for `ref`:

```py
>>> ref.setWhitespaceChars({' ', '\t'}) 
{{'ref:' W:(0123...)} "!"}
>>> ref.whiteChars
{'\t', ' '}
```

But when I try to parse test_string (wrongly formatted), it parses it without error:

```py
>>> test_string = 'ref:\n123\n!'
>>> ref.parseString(test_string)
(['ref:', '123', '!'], {})
```

What am I doing wrong?

### UPD:

It seems that I need to apply `setWhitespaceChars` to EACH element, which must remain on the same line:

```py
>>> import pyparsing as pp
>>> ref = pp.CaselessLiteral('ref:') + pp.Word(pp.nums).setWhitespaceChars(' \t\r') + pp.Literal('!').setWhitespaceChars(' \t\r')
>>> s = 'ref:\n123\n!'
>>> ref.parseString(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected W:(0123...), found '\n'  (at char 4), (line:1, col:5)
```

This adds so much clutter, that I'd probably better call `setDefaultWhitespaceChars` in the beginning and then add newline elements around each expression, which I almost believed I wouldn't need to do with pyparsing. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Please see this recent question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169403/using-pyparsing-to-parse-language-with-signficant-newlines-like-python and if it is a duplicate of yours, then you can just reference it in your question.

Comment: @PaulMcG yes, I finally found time to dig into the question and the answer to it. I think, it's pretty much the same functionality that I asked about. I've added link to the question into the beginning. Looking forward to the new versions! : )